# Get the first id based on category

Tags: jquery

How to get the first id based the category

```
<ul>
    <li id="1" category="A">One</li>
    <li id="2" category="A">Two</li>
    <li id="3" category="B">Three</li>
    <li id="4" category="B">Four</li>
</ul>
```

from the above code i can get the first id by

```
$('ul').find('li:first').attr('id');
```

Suppose i want to get first id based on category, how to get? In my case i want to get first id of category B.(`ans has to be 3`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('ul').find('li[category="B"]').first().attr('id');
```

Also note that your HTML will not be validated because you are not using default attributes. Instead try using the **data-attributes**  that will validate your Markup..

```
<ul>
    <li id="1" data-category="A">One</li>
    <li id="2" data-category="A">Two</li>
    <li id="3" data-category="B">Three</li>
    <li id="4" data-category="B">Four</li>
</ul>​

$('ul').find('li[data-category="B"]').first().attr('id');
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zwZZx/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul').find('li[category=B]').first().attr('id');
```

or

```
$('ul li[category=B]:first').attr('id')
```

whichever style you like(depends on your code)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li[category="A"]:eq(0)').attr('id');
```

or

```
$('ul li[category="A"]:first').attr('id');
```

or

```
$('ul li[category="A"]:nth-child(1)').attr('id');
```

**Note:** `:eq()` starts from 0 while `:nth-child()` starts from 1

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UJdps/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#id of ul").children(":first");
```

or

```
 $("ul li:first").attr("id")
```

Answer (score 1):

does a category always have an ID? if not:

```
$('ul').find('li[category=B][id]:first').attr('id');
```

[JSbin example](http://jsbin.com/idinab/1/)

you should use the HTML data- attribute for category to have a more valid markup